# Why don't languages integrate Dependency Injection at the core?

Tags: c#, java, frameworks, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Why don't languages integrate Dependency Injection in their core (at the lowest level : compilation maybe) since dependencies are the root of all evil in Complexity Theory? This would avoid to use Frameworks.

I'm rather targeting compiled languages.

My question is similar to duck typing that has been introduced recently with dynamics in .NET. Why not something similar in the future for DI?

Comment: PHP is a scripting language. I'm rather targeting compiled languages.

Comment: Because then users of that language wouldn't be able to bicker like children over which framework was best. Seriously though, imagine what would happen if someone came up with a better approach to pattern X (in this case DI) than the one the language implements?

Comment: My point is NO framework so he won't ask himself any question because it would just be natural :)

Comment: @user310291 - no, instead people would just argue over the language's implementation of the *pattern*! A pattern can be implemented in many ways; there is no right or wrong way. This leads to subjectivity and therefore any attempt by a language to mandate that it's done **'this way only'** will just bring the argument about the framework up to the whole language instead!

Speaking of subjectivity that's probably why this question will be closed within the next few minutes!  Although @Aliostad's answer, for me does the trick.

Comment: off topic: duck typing has been in .NET since day one. For example, any object that has a GetEnumerator() method can be used with a foreach loop, it doesn't **have** to implement IEnumerable..

Comment: But not all object has a GetEnumerator() :)

Comment: that's true, what's your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally can see the benefit of this. For instance, I'm writing code like this all the time:

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    // Boilerplate!
    private readonly IDependency1 dep1;
    private readonly IDependency2 dep2;
    private readonly IDependency3 dep3;

    public MyService(IDependency1 dep1, IDependency2 dep2,
        IDependency3 dep3)
    {
        // More boilerplate!
        this.dep1 = dep1;
        this.dep2 = dep2;
        this.dep3 = dep3;
    }

    // Finally something useful
    void IService.DoOperation()
    {
       using (var context = this.dep1.CreateContext())
       {
           this.dep2.Execute(context);

           context.Commit();
       }

       this.dep3.Log("Success");
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it be nice to be able to write it as follows:

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService(private IDependency1 dep1, 
        private IDependency2 dep2, private IDependency3 dep3)
    {
    }

    void IService.DoOperation()
    {
       using (var context = this.dep1.CreateContext())
       {
           this.dep2.Execute(context);

           context.Commit();
       }

       this.dep3.Log("Success");
    }
}
```

I wish I could just leave out all the plumbing with declaring my dependency fields and assigning them in my constructor.

**UPDATE**

Our prayers might have been heard. The C# team [might be adding](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2013/07/anders-on-c-60-at-build-2013.html) "succinct syntax for class definitions" such as us properties that "can be declared directly from the constructor" in C# 6.0. Let's hope such feature makes the light.

So your core question "Why don't languages integrate Dependency Injection at the core?", they do. Scala and F# do already make this much easier and C# will hopefully follow.

In the meantime I've tried to overcome this obstacle by writing a [T4 template that generates the constructor](http://t4ctorgenerator.codeplex.com/) for you in a partial class, but after working with this for a few weeks in an application it really didn't work out as expected.

Comment: Ah at least someone who sees the interest :)

Comment: But this isn't really dependency injection, is it? Anywho, Scala solves this elegantly by having classes parametrized with constructor arguments.

Comment: @Gustafc: The example shows constructor injection, which is a specific form (the most common form) of dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

Because *languages* are **design/design-pattern neutral**.

Comment: dependecies are not pattern: it's about complexity. Being able to inject any type of dependency should be the most wanted and natural feature of a modern language.

Comment: Re: design-pattern neutral: Both C# and Java come with a huge class library that can be considered part of the language, with stuff from collections, to reading configuration files, to XML parsers, to logging libraries and database driver abstraction layers. One could imagine a DI facility would not be totally out of place here.

Comment: We are not talking about JDK or .NET Framework, we are talking about **C# or Java language**. Language is **design-pattern neutral** but yes, `JDK or .NET Framework` **could** provide as such.

Comment: @Thilo: of course not, and in fact DI is part of the Java EE 6 API (JSR 330 and 299)

Comment: @Aliostad: Languages are not design-pattern neutral. Patterns as observer, iterator, and template method are baked into the C# language from day one.

Comment: @Steven C# language and .NET framework, they are different things. We are talking about C#/Java and not the others. Can you give an example of an observer in C#?

Comment: IObserver has been created in .NET 3.5 no ?

Comment: `IObserver` is an interface in .NET Fx... We are talking about language features.

Comment: @Aliostad: .NET events are an implementation of the observer design pattern. C# even has a keyword for this: `event`.

Comment: No, they are not. Iterator pattern, observer pattern, bridge pattern, and few others are built into the very core of .NET

Answer (score 2):

As Grodon says in the comments: Function/method parameters are dependency injection - and pretty much all languages support those at the lowest levels.

DI frameworks are usually tailored towards server environments. Language mechanisms would simply be the wrong level of abstraction for that.

Comment: "DI frameworks are usually tailored towards server environments." I don't agree! DI frameworks can be used (and are used) for client applications, such as Silverlight, Forms and WPF all the time.

Comment: And I forgot to mention Windows Services of course :-)

Answer (score 2):

They do, actually, by letting you pass parameters to methods/constructors/functions - and that's pretty much all there is to it, what DI frameworks do is just a fancy way of specifying parameter values.

A more interesting question would be how to *enforce* dependency injection on a language level. Banning `static` state is probably a good start (like Newspeak does).

Answer (score 1):

That's inherently a flawed approach. Ideally, languages should be as lean as possible, but be powerful enough to introduce arbitrary language-level abstractions (think LISP and metaprogramming). If not, where do you draw the line between what to include and what to leave out?

As for introducing compilation-level support for DI, that's just impossible. Your application might use dynamically linked libraries of sorts, and these might not be even known at compile-time. Think plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If a language is flexible enough, it can *simulate* DI. Java and C# are clearly not, but functional or hybrid languages often are. E.g. in Haskell you could use a Reader Monad to hold an "environment" without littering your code, or maybe you could use type classes. Scala has mixin composition and implicit objects, which could both be utilized for this. So I would conclude that a language that really *needs* DI just lacks appropriate and powerful abstraction mechanisms.